# logcat window disappears android studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio

I have just upgraded Android Studio to version 3.1 and it seems like the actual log lines are in a `logcat` pop-up window that pops up when i enter `logcat` as described in the embeded photo, but sometimes this doesnt pop up and i cant find how to make it pop again.

I tried pressing Alt-6 multiple times

How to solve this?

[image: logcat]

Comment: Did you find a solution?